# Is printing negative numbers as characters well-defined in C?

Tags: c, char, printf

For example, the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a;
    signed char b;
    for(a = CHAR_MIN, b = CHAR_MIN; a < CHAR_MAX ; a++, b++ )
    printf("%c %c\n", a, b);
}
```

outputs:

```
! !
" "
# #
$ $
% %
& &
' '
( (
……
```

When `a` and `b` are negative, characters are still printed on the screen. I wonder whether this behaviour is well-defined?

If so, is it defined by the standard or an specific implementation? And what's the point of defining such behaviour?

Comment: %c is for printing characters.  Try %d.

Comment: @bruceg I know, and I used "%c" on purpose, because I want to know how "%c" works when negative values are passed.

Comment: If printing with %c format the bit pattern is converted to a character.  Try a simple loop **for( int c= -127 ; c < 128 ; c++ )printf(" %d %c\n",c,c);** and study the output, together with an ASCII table.

Comment: @ Arif Burhan Testing, as you suggested, is a good step.  Yet certainly OP was looking for something more that knowing if it works on one machine - to know if it is well defined and code can count on reliable output, not only a a single tested machine, but others as well.

Comment: Your example code is a bad example for your question, as what the code is doing is more dependent on the behavior of assigning out-of-range values is instead of the actual print.   You should change your example to be using -100 instead of -200... and not assigning negative numbers to unsigned values.

Comment: @xaxxon Question improved

Comment: The question is completely different now to how it was originally..

Comment: "what's the point of defining such behaviour?"  - so that you can supply `char` and `unsigned char` as argument interchangeably (and as a corollary, values returned by `getchar`). Also, so that the library does not need to change in response to the compiler defining plain char as either signed or unsigned.

Comment: @M.M Edited again. My point is **When a and b are negative, characters are still printed on the screen.**

Comment: @sunqingyao some characters (half of them , in fact) have negative values on common implementations. The range of `char` is `CHAR_MIN` through to `CHAR_MAX` which is typically -128 to 127, and those are all characters

Comment: @M.M Yes, I suppose the first few `char`s (half) are negative, which are posted in the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

When a value is passed to match `"%c"` is it converted to an `int` or `unsigned` as part of the usual integer promotions due to the `...` of the `printf()` arguments.

When `printf()` see that `int` value, it converts to to an `unsigned char`.  Then the corresponding character is printed.

> `c` If no `l` length modifier is present, the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written. C11dr §7.21.6.1 8

So passing any narrow type integer that is promoted to `int` or even an `unsigned` within the range of `INT_MAX` is not a problem.

Comment: Does this imply that only `unsigned char`s can be output directly? Then why the prototype of `putchar()` is `int putchar ( int character );`, rather than `int putchar ( unsigned char character );`?

Comment: For details on " even an unsigned within the range of INT_MAX is not a problem.", see §6.5.2.2 6

Comment: And "the point", of course, is that a 'negative' char value has no meaning when applied to 'printable text'. Perhaps this is a leftover from a time when printable character codes were fetched through a lookup table - fetching from a lookup table with a negative index is UB, and potentially dangerous. So a safeguard was built in. (All purely conjecture.)

Comment: @sun qingyao (squeezing another question in) --> `putchar()` follows `fputc()` which also converts the `int` to a `unsigned char` before printing.  Why?  History - C functions historically have not accepted arguments narrower than `int/unsigned` as that was most expeditious in coding at the time..

Comment: @RadLexus That's a bit strange: C doesn't even have bound-checking, isn't that more dangerous? I mean most potentially fatal practices in C are simply left undefined. Also, converting an `int` to `unsigned char` each time a "%c" is printed does cost something(at least on old implementations)

Comment: @sun qingyao "imply that only unsigned chars can be output directly?" --> No. Use `fputwc()`.

Comment: @sunqingyao: C itself has no array bounds check but the implementation of a function surely may. (That said: I checked Apple's implementation of `printf` and that, at least, just seems to forward the problem to `write`.)

Comment: @sunqingyao "converting an int to unsigned char each time a "%c" is printed does cost something(at least on old implementations" --> not likely.  The whole point of `int` is that is the "natural" size of integer processing.  Processors performing narrower or wider operations typically reduce their performance.  Of course, YMMV.

Comment: @sunqingyao the `getchar` and related functions use `int` so that they can represent EOF in-band.  `putchar` was designed before function prototypes were invented, so for backwards compatibility `unsigned char` could not be used in the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

200 is 11001000 (in binary number), so -200 is 100111000 by one's complement.

The size of 'char' is just 8 bits, and -200 is 00111000 (= 56 in decimal number).

ASCII code of 56 is '8', and that's why you can see '8' as your output.

If you print out it as '%d', you can see '56' as an output.

Comment: one's complement of 11001000 is 00110111, my machine uses two's compliment anyway

Comment: "The size of 'char' is just 8 bits, and -200 is 00111000 (= 56 in decimal number)"   I don't think that's guaranteed.